# Cannot filter pdfs and txt files in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, windows-10, openfiledialog

I have been using this filter to filter pdfs and other files.

```
 ChooseDocumnetOfd.Filter = "Pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf |Office Files|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt |Txt files (*.txt); *.txt | ";
```

It had been working well for a long time. However, I can only filter Word files now.
Why can't I filter any other type of file now?

Comment: I never changed the code. But it just doesn't work now

Comment: You will always learn more if you read the documentation first before asking a question (they have it in just about every language) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a valid filter string; you're missing a pipe symbol after the Txt files entry, and there's an extraneous pipe at the end. It should look like this:

```
ChooseDocumnetOfd.Filter = "Pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Office Files|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt|Txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have written:

```
 ChooseDocumnetOfd.Filter = "Pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Office files (*doc, *.xls, *.ppt)|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt|Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Ive no idea explanation as to why it was working before; what you have in your question doesn't follow the rules laid out in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

The basic rule is:

```
description1|extensionlist1|description2|extensionlist2...
```

Multiple extensions delimited by semicolon. Descriptions can contain any text and don't have to contain the extension list